# Ionic 5 Capacitor 3 sqlite.requestPermission() not showing dialog box

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am trying to use CapacitorSQLite with capacitor 3. When I call SQLite.requestPermission() its not showing any dialog box asking for permission and the code seems to be never returning from that call as I can see logs before that call but not after.

code look like

```
async init(): Promise<void> {
    if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      try {
        const sqlite:any = CapacitorSQLite;
        console.log('setting permission handler');
          this.handlerPermissions = sqlite.addListener(
              'androidPermissionsRequest', async (data:any) => { 
              if (data.permissionGranted === 1) {
                console.log('Perm granted');
                this.setupDatabase();
              } else {
                console.log("Permission not granted");
              }      
          });
          console.log('REQUESTING PERMS');
        await sqlite.requestPermissions();
        
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('error on perm req',e);
        const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
          header: 'No DB access',
          message: e.message,
          buttons: ['OK']
        });
        await alert.present();
      }
    } else {
      console.log('not running on android platform');
      const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
        header: 'Not android',
        message: this.platform.platforms()[0],
        buttons: ['OK']
      });
      await alert.present();
      this.setupDatabase();
    }
  }
```

can see the following logs

'setting permission handler'
'REQUESTING PERMS'

but am also expecting one of the following as well

'Perm granted'
"Permission not granted"
'error on perm req'

here's AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest package="io.ionic.starter" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:label="@string/title_activity_main" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="io.ionic.starter.MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    
</manifest>
```

Am I missing anything? Capacitor doc says plug will have user-permission that need to be added but couldn't see any for sqlite.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Which plugin do you use? I thought SQLite don't need any requests for permissions.

Comment: I am using Capacitor-community-sqlite https://github.com/capacitor-community/sqlite

Comment: At least the latest version of this plugin has not `addListener` function. Anyway, you should set up permission only in the `Manifest` file if needed.

Comment: Yup, you are right. requestPermission is not needed in v3. It creates database and connection fine. However it throws error connection already exist when trying to read data (but if I check isconnection then it returns false). Any idea how connections should be open and managed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need specific permissions for this plugin. Check the documentation for examples of how to use this plugin in [Angular](https://github.com/capacitor-community/sqlite/blob/master/docs/Ionic-Angular-Usage.md), [React](https://github.com/capacitor-community/sqlite/blob/master/docs/Ionic-React-Usage.md) or [Vue](https://github.com/capacitor-community/sqlite/blob/master/docs/Ionic-Vue-Usage.md) depends on what you need.